# Does Android preform pre-compilation optimization

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and I am trying understand something pretty fundamental, or at least I think it is.
I saw this example in a course Im taking.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    while(true) {
        val x = 1
    }
}
```

The aim of this IS to get the app to stop responding, however I would expect that in the compilation stage the java/kotlin compiler would optimize this part out after the first time as it would happen if you run the same code in C but it doesn't and the app is frozen.
I've played around with C and I couldn't overload a processor until I used a rand call in the while loop and assigned it.

My question is how and if the compiler does a pre run optimization and where can I read about it  and would this code overload a processor in a phone

Comment: "would optimize this part out" how can you optimize this out without changing the semantics?

Comment: Not me, the C compiler and I would expect a similar process in Java/Kotlin.

Comment: how can the C compiler optimize this out without changing the semantics? By the specification of Java and Kotlin, this should never complete normally. An optimization must not change that; it's a pretty funky thing that a C compiler would.

Comment: the pre-compiler in c changes the code, https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html for example if you have a function call and it's only few line it will paste it instead of the call and won't jump to that lin of code

Comment: @AndyTurner I've just realized I've missed something, the C compiler will assign x = 1 ONCE and skip this line until x will be assigned a different value. Both loops and function will not end. Now the question is will the Java/kotlin code overload the processor or like C it will optimize it out.